# Replace [0-9] with 0[0-9]

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to know if there is a way to add a 0 in front of every 1 digit number using `regex`.

The input string is a list of 1-3 numbers separated by a '-' (i.e. `28`, `12-56`, `67-6`, `45-65-46`).

The two issues I have come across are:

1. Matching all the possible 1 digit numbers without doing a seperate check for each of the below: `^[0-9]-`, `-[0-9]-`, `^[0-9]&`, `-[0-9]&`
2. Adding the 0 without removing anything else. So turn: `Regex.Replace(input, "^[0-9]-","0")` into something like: `Regex.Replace(input, "^[0-9]-","^0[0-9]-")`

Comment: Try `Regex.Replace(s, @"\b\d\b", "0$&")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- search: `(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)`
- replace `0$1`

Where:

- `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind that makes sure we haven't a digit before the match.
- `(\d)` is a capture group, that is referenced by `$1` in the replacement part.
- `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure we haven't a digit after the match.

See [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for info.

This replaces digit not preceeded or followed by other digit by `0` + the digit.

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)","0$1")
```

Comment: So `Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)","0$1")` ?

Comment: @nickzoum: Yes, it is.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working. But could you explain in your answer how it works. Cause, so far I only get that \d searches for a number (right?) , and that `0$1` adds a 0 and the matched string.

Comment: Wouldn't just this: `(\d)(?!\d)` or just this: `(?<!\d)(\d)` work as the search parameter?

Comment: @nickzoum:No, it doesn't because we have to test there're no digits on left side and on right side. the two ones you propose matche more than one digit.

Comment: BTW, in Javascript, this also works too: `var s = s.replace(/(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)/g,'0$1');`. I was able to take something like '1/1/2021' and make it '01/01/2021', and it also worked properly against strings like '12/1/2020' and '1/12/2020' too, prefixing a 0 as it should before the numbers, creating a format like XX/XX/XXXX.